# Spring RestTemplate getForObject URL not working for Apple iTunes

Tags: java, spring, spring-rest

I created the following simple test to query iTunes:

```
@Test
fun loadArtist()
{
    val restTemplate = RestTemplate()

    val builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("https://itunes.apple.com/search")
    builder.queryParam("term", "howling wolf")
    builder.queryParam("entity", "allArtist")
    builder.queryParam("limit", 1)

    println("\n\nURL ${builder.toUriString()}")

    val result = restTemplate.getForObject(builder.toUriString(), String::class.java);
    println("Got artist: $result")
}
```

**And the output was unexpected:**

```
URL https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=howling%20wolf&entity=allArtist&limit=1
Got artist: 

{
 "resultCount":0,
 "results": []
}
```

**Pasting the generated URL into a browser *does* give expected results - artist returned.**

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=howling%20wolf&entity=allArtist&limit=1

Also, hard-coding the query works:

```
val result = restTemplate.getForObject("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=howling%20wolf&entity=allArtist&limit=1", String::class.java);
```

. . the problem only seems to occur for `term` queries that include spaces.

What went wrong? Other than assemble the URL by hand, how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a case of double encoding the whitespace. From the RestTemplate Javadoc:

> For each HTTP method there are three variants: two accept a URI
>   template string and URI variables (array or map) while a third accepts
>   a URI. Note that for URI templates it is assumed encoding is
>   necessary, e.g. restTemplate.getForObject("http://example.com/hotel
>   list") becomes "http://example.com/hotel%20list". This also means if
>   the URI template or URI variables are already encoded, double encoding
>   will occur, e.g. http://example.com/hotel%20list becomes
>   http://example.com/hotel%2520list). To avoid that use a URI method
>   variant to provide (or re-use) a previously encoded URI. To prepare
>   such an URI with full control over encoding, consider using
>   UriComponentsBuilder.

So it looks like getForObject will actually query for https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=howling%2520wolf&entity=allArtist&limit=1 and thus result in an empty result. You can always just replace whitespaces with a "+" in your term or try to make one of those classes skip the encoding process.

Comment: The first thing I did was try using "+" instead, but it didn't seem to work, actually.

Comment: No, since it was a very simple case I just used: `val term = name.replace(oldChar = ' ', newChar = '+'); val response = URL("${this.url}?entity=allArtist&limit=1&term=$term").readText()` and then mapped with Jackson. It still bothers me a little that RestTemplate didn't work though.