# iTunes Lookup API response is different for different clients

Tags: http, request, itunes-store, apple-music

Right now it looks like a mystery. Please help me in solving it.

I use iTunes public API to fetch an album: "Metallica" by Metallica (see it in browser: [US](https://music.apple.com/us/album/metallica/579372950) region, [MV](https://music.apple.com/mv/album/metallica/579372950) region). I construct the following URLs to fetch it via API:

1. US region https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=579372950&country=US&entity=album - works
2. MV region https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=579372950&country=MV&entity=album - doesn't work

Here's the actual behaviour I observe:

- If I query `GET https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=579372950&country=MV&entity=album` in a Spring app (using `RestTemplate` + Jackson `HttpMessageConverter`) I get an empty response:

  ```
  {
   "resultCount":0,
   "results": []
  }
  ```
- If I navigate to https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=579372950&country=MV&entity=album in a browser I get a file download prompt. The file contains an empty response:

  ```
  {
   "resultCount":0,
   "results": []
  }
  ```
- If I query API using HttpPie `http get https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=579372950&country=MV&entity=album` I get a non-empty response !!!

  ```
  {
      "resultCount": 1,
      "results": [
          {
              "amgArtistId": 4906,
              "artistId": 3996865,
              "artistName": "Metallica",
              "artistViewUrl": "https://music.apple.com/us/artist/metallica/3996865?uo=4",
              "artworkUrl100": "https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/0b/9c/d2/0b9cd2e7-6e76-8912-0357-14780cc2616a/source/100x100bb.jpg",
              "artworkUrl60": "https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/0b/9c/d2/0b9cd2e7-6e76-8912-0357-14780cc2616a/source/60x60bb.jpg",
              "collectionCensoredName": "Metallica",
              "collectionExplicitness": "notExplicit",
              "collectionId": 579372950,
              "collectionName": "Metallica",
              "collectionPrice": 9.99,
              "collectionType": "Album",
              "collectionViewUrl": "https://music.apple.com/us/album/metallica/579372950?uo=4",
              "copyright": "℗ 1991 Blackened Recordings",
              "country": "USA",
              "currency": "USD",
              "primaryGenreName": "Metal",
              "releaseDate": "1991-08-12T07:00:00Z",
              "trackCount": 13,
              "wrapperType": "collection"
          }
      ]
  }
  ```

I tried it multiple times and the results seem to be consistent. I compared the requests and they seem to be identical.

Why does iTunes respond differently to different clients? I can't understand. What important detail am I missing?

---

Similar questions:

1. [Spring RestTemplate getForObject URL not working for Apple iTunes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34312565/1429387) - there's another problem (double encoding of the whitespace character).

---

This problem happens to the following regions (it's a complete list):

- LI https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=579372950&country=LI&entity=album
- MV https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=579372950&country=MV&entity=album
- MM https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=579372950&country=MM&entity=album
- ET https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=579372950&country=ET&entity=album
- RS https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=579372950&country=RS&entity=album

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spotted a difference:

- `http get 'https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=579372950&country=MV&entity=album'` -> empty response
- `curl 'https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=579372950&country=MV&entity=album'` -> empty response
- `http get https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=579372950&country=MV&entity=album` -> 1 album in response
- `curl https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=579372950&country=MV&entity=album` -> 1 album in response

if I don't use quotes around URL, the request is interpreted as `GET https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=579372950`. the default country is US and therefore I see 1 US album in response.